# Elastic Beanstalk confused about application versions?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

When I run `eb deploy` I get
`ERROR: You cannot have more than 500 Application Versions. Either remove some Application Versions or request a limit increase.`

however, there is currently only one version of the application, and I can't delete that one because it is deployed. below is a screenshot of my terminal:

[image: topmost is the output of eb appversion]

My research so far indicates this should work, but a bug in en EB seems unlikely. what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the limit of 500 is on the number of application versions across ***all*** applications in the given region for your AWS account number. You verify this by executing:

`aws elasticbeanstalk describe-application-versions --region <your region> | grep VersionLabel | wc -l`

You can also [request AWS to increase the limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html) on the number of app versions if you choose not to delete any of existing application versions.